# TV Style remote that can be mapped to keypresses

Tags: remote-control, driver

For a project I'm working on I need to get people to interact with a mac using a TV Style Remote.

I want to map some of the buttons (Left, Right, Up, Down, Red, Yellow, Green, Blue and Select) to simulate keypresses.

Can anyone point me in the direction of something that might be suitable for a machine running Snow Leopard. I've seen several solutions targeting at Windows MCE but none of them have had Mac support.

The standard apple remote, or an iPod/iPad remote app aren't suitable for this project.

Comment: How does the remote communicate? IR?

Comment: @Odinulf.  I haven't found a specific remote I plan to use, I've seen some that use IR and a couple that use RF. Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found Remote Buddy from http://www.iospirit.com/

It looks like it will do what I'm looking for and works with a wide range of hardware.

I'll try to pick up a compatible remote and see how I get on.

Comment: Yes, I have used Remote Buddy.  Just with the remote that came with the Mac, but to control apps other than the few default ones.

Comment: @GEdgar, it works well with the PS3 remote too, a little fiddly to setup all the custom behaviours, but once configured is great.